# issue with File variables

Tags: c++

The payRate hourWorked and employNum variables say they are not uninitialized. Not sure what is going wrong here. I'm trying to gather info from a file and then calculate data and show it on screen.

```
 {
        int x;
        double y;
        double employNum;
        double payRate;
        double hourWorked;
        double grossAmount;
        bool employChecker;
        double netCalc;
        cout << "Welcome to the employee data menu!" << endl;
        employChecker = false;
        do

        {

            cout << "Please enter :" << endl << "1: To view  an employees Data" << endl << "0: To retirn to the main menu" << endl;
            cin >> x;
            if (x = 1)
            {
                cout << "Please enter the employee number that you would like data on" << endl;
                cin >> y;
                cout << "Employee Num" << setw(10) << "Hours" << setw(20) << "Rate" << setw(30) << "Gross" << setw(40) << "Net" << setw(50) << "Fes" << setw(60) << "State" << setw(70) << "Soc Sec" << setw(80) << endl;
                ifstream  myFileIn("inText.txt");
                while (myFileIn, employNum, payRate, hourWorked)
                {
                    if (employNum == y)
                    {
                        employChecker = true;
                        if (hourWorked >= 35)
                        {
                            grossAmount = ((hourWorked * payRate)*.15);
                        }
                        else if(hourWorked < 40)
                        {
                            grossAmount = ((40 * payRate) * ((hourWorked - 40)*1.5));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            grossAmount = (hourWorked * payRate);
                        }
                        netCalc = grossAmount - (grossAmount * STATE_TAX) + (grossAmount * SOC_TAX) + (grossAmount * FEDERAL_TAX);
                        cout << employNum << setw(10) << hourWorked << setw(20) << payRate << setw(30) << grossAmount << setw(40) << netCalc << setw(50) << (grossAmount * FEDERAL_TAX) << setw(60) << (grossAmount * STATE_TAX) << setw(70) << (grossAmount * SOC_TAX) << setw(80) << endl;
                    }
                }
                if (employChecker == false)
                {
                    cout << "Employee does not exist or there was an error computing epmloyees data!" << endl;
                }

            }
        } while (x != 0);
        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: Try to initialize them in the declaration: double employNum = 0;

Comment: You're trying to check their values without them being initialized to any value. Which means that they still contain garbage. You must set them to a value before trying to read them. This is probably done by reading the values to those variables from the file.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders for informing my on the necessity of thank you, and appreciation. Life would be so much more simple if we were robots.

Come on now, we're grasping at straws arn't we?

Comment: Did you bother to read the link?  Stack Overflow is not like other sites you may have used before. Please take the time to learn how it is different.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I actually did read it. It seems like a hot controversial topic..

Comment: I've made many posts on here and, _just sayin_ the  C++ threads are the only ones where I run into people complain about such mundane things. [http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/](The Great Edit Wars), I think you, my friend, are the one who needs to learn how things work. You're nothing but rude and condescending in your posts... Remember, this is not a site for the elite got gather, it's a place for Q/A.

Comment: I'm not complaining. I'm letting you know about the change I made, and I'm telling you why I made it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The payRate hourWorked and employNum varibles say they are not uninitialized

The compiler tells you what you've done wrong: you did not initialize these variables, so they might have *any* value, including things like `0.0` (which would be `false` in your while loop), but you use them in your `while` loop.

You could do something like

`double payRate = 0.0;`

to solve that ambiguity.

All in all, I haven't thoroughly read your code, but it's almost never correct to simply use a concatenated list of floating point expressions in a while loop:

```
while (myFileIn, employNum, payRate, hourWorked)
```

I really don't know what you wanted to do, but this clearly indicates you will have to go back and learn C++ basics. The content of `(myFileIn, employNum, payRate, hourWorked)` is always the value of `hourWorked`, and I'm pretty sure that's not what you wanted to test for in your loop iteration condition.

Comment: Doesn't "not uninitialized" mean "initialized"? :-)